# Loading .mat files

Tags: python, scipy

I have the following code for loading .mat files

```
import scipy.io as sio
data = pd.DataFrame(sio.loadmat('data.mat').values()).iloc[7]
```

Loading these files takes several minutes to load. I believe the issue is from a convert the list to a pandas dataframe. The .mat files are not particularly large: only about 33MB

Comment: Have you compared, how long does MATLAB load these big files? If the time is similar, then probably you know the answer.

Comment: How large? 1 GB?

Comment: `loadmat` docs says you can select variable names, and possibly save some load time.

Comment: I think the issue is when I convert the list I've imported to a pandas data frame. I realize that just loading the .mat files doesn't take long, it's transforming them form list to pd.DataFrame()